# CFC return multiple queries to cfselect

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfc

I have a single cffunction which returns multiple queries. I'm using 'struct' as my returntype. My question is, how do I use function returns in multiple cfselects. I can get the cfdump to work, but not sure what to put in

```
cfc
 <cffunction name="cfcName" access="remote" returntype="struct">
  <cfset var myStruct=StructNew()>

  <!---Query1---->
  <cfquery name="Query1" datasource="dsn">
   SELECT DISTINCT Col1
   FROM Table1
   ORDER BY Col1 
  </cfquery>

  <!---Query2---->
  <cfquery name="Query2" datasource="dsn">
   SELECT DISTINCT Col2
   FROM table2
   ORDER BY Col2 
  </cfquery>

  <cfset myStruct.Query1= Query1>
  <cfset myStruct.Query2= Query2>

  <cfreturn myStruct>
</cffunction>

<cfinvoke
  component="CMPT"
  method="cfcName"
  returnvariable="Return_cfcName">
</cfinvoke>


cfm,
(Query 1 returns should diplay in this cfselect)
<cfselect name="Select1" required="no" query="?" value="?" display="?" queryPosition="below">
        <option value="">ALL</option>
</cfselect>

(Query 2 returns should diplay in this cfselect)
<cfselect name="Select2" required="no" query="?" value="?" display="?" queryPosition="below">
        <option value="">ALL</option>
</cfselect>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
<cfselect name="Select1" required="no" query="Return_cfcName.Query1" value="Col1" display="Col1" queryPosition="below">
        <option value="">ALL</option>
</cfselect>


<cfselect name="Select2" required="no" query="Return_cfcName.Query2" value="Col2" display="Col2" queryPosition="below">
        <option value="">ALL</option>
</cfselect>
```

Comment: you are a star, that works. I had <.....query='Return_cfcName.Query1' value='Return_cfcName.Col1' display='Return_cfcName.Col1'>. Changed it like you've mentioned, now it works like a charm. Thanks again